# Find at least one solution from series of variable comparisons

Tags: algorithm

At work, I am facing an algorithmic problem. The generalized version of the problem is

> Given a set of comparisons between two variables (Greater than or less than). Find at least one single inequation with all variables in it that complies with the comparisons above.

For example having A > B, B > C, D > A, E > C. One answer is D > A > B > E > C. Note that there can be multiple answers but just one answer is enough. There can also be a conflict that there is no answer.

I want to know if there is a name for this kind of problem and what is the best practice to solve this without having to check all combinations.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a good question. Have you heard about **`Topological sort`** in `Graph theory`.

Think it to be like this. `x > y` means that there is a directed edge from `x to y` (like `x ---> y`). So, basically you have a network of directed edges connecting vertices `A B C D and E`. Apply [topological sort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/) to get the answer.

Topological sort basically means that in the list of the vertices obtained after the sort, `x` will always appear before `y` if there is a directed edge from x to y.

Comment: Topological sorting is the translation of the problem to graph theory realm. I believe that a more accurate term is [partial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

Comment: @alfasin Well, I don't know exactly what a partial order is. But, topological sort can solve his problem if he has a adjacency list, isn't it? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you don't know what partial ordering is you can go to the link I provided in the previous comment, read & learn. After all, this is why we're in Stackoverflow (to learn) isn't it ? :)

Comment: @alfasin Sorry (I did look at the link). But I was never really into Maths. I know a bit of graph theory and using DFS and time of finishing, the OP can easily solve his problem.

Comment: Thank you! The topological sort is what I am looking for. The conflict in the comparisons is described as cyclic graph too. Regarding partial ordering, I was trying to understand but still no luck. Maybe I'll stick with topological sort.